# How can I make a variable borrow for 'static?

Tags: rust, lifetime

In `vulkano`, to create a `CPUAccessibleBuffer` you need give it some data and the `CPUAccessibleBuffer::from_data` function requires the data to have the `'static` lifetime.

I have some data in `&[u8]` array (created at runtime) that I would like to pass to that function.

However, it errors with this message

```
argument requires that `data` is borrowed for `'static`
```

So how can I make the lifetime of the data `'static` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`CpuAccessibleBuffer::from_iter`](https://docs.rs/vulkano/0.26.0/vulkano/buffer/cpu_access/struct.CpuAccessibleBuffer.html#method.from_iter) instead, it does the same thing but does not require the collection to be `Copy` or `'static`:

```
let data: &[u8] = todo!();

let _ = CpuAccessibleBuffer::from_iter(
    device,
    usage,
    host_cached,
    data.iter().copied(), // <--- pass like so
);
```

Or if you actually have a `Vec<u8>`, you can pass it directly:

```
let data: Vec<u8> = todo!();

let _ = CpuAccessibleBuffer::from_iter(
    device,
    usage,
    host_cached,
    data, // <--- pass like so
);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you **really** must create the data at runtime, and you **really** need to last for `'static`, then you can use one of the memory leaking methods such as [`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) or [`Vec::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.leak) to deliberately leak a heap allocation and ensure it is never freed.

While leaking memory is normally something one avoids, in this case it's actually a sensible thing to do. If the data must live forever then leaking it is actually the correct thing to do, semantically speaking. You *don't* want the memory to be freed, not ever, which is exactly what happens when memory is leaked.

Example:

```rust
fn require_static_data(data: &'static [u8]) {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main() {
    let data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    require_static_data(data.leak());
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=889f155197ff3caa92d367bc8dda22dc)</sup>

That said, really think over the *really*s I led with. Make sure you understand why the code you're calling wants `'static` data and ask yourself why your data isn't already `'static`.

- Is it possible to create the data at compile time? Rust has a powerful build time macro system. It's possible, for example, to use [`include_bytes!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_bytes.html) to read in a file and do some processing on it before it's embedded into your executable.
- Is there another API you can use, another function call you're not seeing that doesn't require `'static`?

(These questions aren't for you specifically, but for anyone who comes across this Q&A in the future.)

Comment: You deserve the +1 for `include_bytes!` at a minimum.  That's just wild for compile-time reading in of files/data.  I can see how useful that could be, and yet also how utterly abused it would be by some developers I know.  And on occasion, I'll admit I'll probably be both types of developer!

Answer (score 1):

If the data is created at runtime, it can't have a static lifetime. Static means that data is present for the whole lifetime of the program, which is necessary in some contexts, especially when threading is involved. One way for data to be static is, as Paul already answered, explicitly declaring it as such, i.e.:

```rust
static constant_value: i32 = 0;
```

However, there's no universally applicable way to make arbitrary data static. This type of inference is made at compile-time by the borrow checker, not by the programmer.

Usually if a function requires `'static` (type) arguments (as in this case) it means that anything less could potentially be unsafe, and you need to reorganize the way data flows in and out of your program to provide this type of data safely. Unfortunately, that's not something SO can provide within the scope of this question.

Answer (score -3):

Make a constant with `static` lifetime:

```
static NUM: i32 = 18;
```

Comment: Please take a look at [@CtrlAltF2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69888238/3025856), which was posted around the same time as yours, for the level of detail we like to see for answers on Stack Overflow.